# @angular/service-worker silent failure

Tags: angular-service-worker

I have used the `@angular/service-worker` module successfully in several projects but am running into a silent failure issue on my latest project that I can't seem to debug. My configuration and setup is identical to other projects, and the outputted build (via CLI v1.6.2) seems correct:

[dist (partial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmuxx.png)

My initial thought was there was something wrong with my environment variable so I went through logging to ensure `enabled` was `true` after build, even went as far as hardcoding it in all environments just to test:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: true
})
```

Yet still when I run the app, whether locally with `http-server` or in a dev or qa environment with prod mode enabled there is no service worker registered in dev tools and no errors or warnings in the console:

[service worker tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw8bX.png)

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing a silent failure in this case? I have wracked my brain, compared working solutions vs this and cannot seem to come up with a solution. Also, is there any way to further debug this type of scenario?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this workaround in your main.ts file:

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8779#issuecomment-350737663) there may be some problems in your codebase or in your dependencies. I prefer use the workaround for now until an official solution is given by the angular team.